# Joining two names from data base

Tags: mysql, string, join

I have code like that And I need to join `name` and `surname` (make like one string). I will use it for Search system. I want type name and get other options with same name but diferent surnames 
How can I do this?

```
$query = "SELECT `name`, `surname` FROM `people` WHERE `name` `surname`
LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'" ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
$query = "SELECT `name`, `surname` FROM `people` WHERE CONCAT(`name`, " ", `surname`)
LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'" ;
```

Comment: Thank you for solution ! Only I changed  double quotation marks to simple simple quotes.